# How to display ID-Description in Grid Field in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb, displayformat

In Acumatica How to display ID-Description format for Selector Field in Grid?

Answer (score 0):

In Acumatica ASPX Page We have to add a Property called DisplayMode="Hint" to get ID-Description format in Selector Fields of Grid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).